# Using pipes to pass struct information

Tags: c, struct, pipe, fork

I am trying to passing struct information between the parent and the child process using pipes but couldn't manage to catch my error. I would be really grateful if you can show me the way or give suggestions to improve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Student {
    int ID;
    char Name[10];
};


int main() {
    int i;
    struct Student student[5] = {0, '\0'};
    char *Names[5] = {"David", "Roger", "Syd", "Richard", "Nick"};
    pid_t pid = fork();
    char *info[3];
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Fork failed.");
        exit(1);

    }


    else if (pid == 0) {// Child
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("Child Process: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            student[i].ID = i + 1;
            strcpy(student[i].Name, Names[i]);
        }

        write(fd[0], student[0].ID, sizeof(int));

        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            printf("Student name is: %s, ID is: %d\n", student[i].Name, student[i].ID);
        }

        printf("Child Process has been completed.\n");


    }

    else {// Parent
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd[0]);


        read(fd[1], student[0].ID, sizeof(student));

        printf("\nParent Process Print\n");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            printf("Student name is: %s, ID is: %d\n", student[i].Name, student[i].ID);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

Child Process:
Student name is: David, ID is: 1
Student name is: Roger, ID is: 2
Student name is: Syd, ID is: 3
Student name is: Richard, ID is: 4
Student name is: Nick, ID is: 5
Child Process has been completed.

Parent Process Print
Student name is: , ID is: 0
Student name is: , ID is: 0
Student name is: , ID is: 0
Student name is: , ID is: 0
Student name is: , ID is: 0

Comment: try creating the pipe *before* calling fork

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  Remove the C++ tag?

Comment: Also your `read()` and `write()` calls look wrong.

Comment: You're writing just the id but trying to read the whole struct? Shouldn't the input to read and write be pointers not the id value?

Comment: Looks like the read and write ends of the pipe are backward, too (should read from `fd[0]` and write to `fd[1]`).

Comment: @Dmitri covered  the main issue, and you don't loop in the parent over the `read()`.  And you need to pass the address of  ID `&student[0].ID` to read/write.  Also, you need to index `student[i]` otherwise you send the first one over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the following issues:

1. Initialization of `student` was wrong.  Reduced scope to either child and parent, and just initialized the two variables to focus on problem at hand.
2. Swapped pipe used between client and server
3. Fixed write to send each student id (integer used as address, and student array not being index)
4. Fixed read to read each student id (integer used as address, not being read in a loop)
5. Reduced scope of `i` to a loop variable
6. Enhanced to send and receive Name, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct Student {
    int ID;
    char Name[10];
};

int main() {
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd)) {
        printf("pipe failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            printf("Fork failed.");
            return 1;
            break;
        case 0: {
            close(fd[0]);
            struct Student student[5] = {
                { 1, "David" },
                { 2, "Roger" },
                { 3, "Syd" },
                { 4, "Richard" },
                { 5, "Nick" },
            };
            printf("Child Process: \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("Student name is: %s, ID is: %d\n", student[i].Name, student[i].ID);
                write(fd[1], &student[i].ID, sizeof(student[i].ID));
                size_t len = strlen(student[i].Name);
                write(fd[1], &len, sizeof(len));
                write(fd[1], student[i].Name, len);
            }
            printf("Child Process has been completed.\n");
            break;
        }
        default: {
            struct Student student[5] = { 0 };
            wait(NULL);
            close(fd[1]);
            printf("\nParent Process Print\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                read(fd[0], &student[i].ID, sizeof(student[i].ID));
                size_t len;
                read(fd[0], &len, sizeof(len));
                read(fd[0], student[i].Name, len);
                printf("Student name is: %s, ID is: %d\n", student[i].Name, student[i].ID);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
Child Process:
Student name is: David, ID is: 1
Student name is: Roger, ID is: 2
Student name is: Syd, ID is: 3
Student name is: Richard, ID is: 4
Student name is: Nick, ID is: 5
Child Process has been completed.

Parent Process Print
Student name is: David, ID is: 1
Student name is: Roger, ID is: 2
Student name is: Syd, ID is: 3
Student name is: Richard, ID is: 4
Student name is: Nick, ID is: 5
```